# KiCAD: Footprint for pushbutton (arduino)

Tags: button, kicad, footprint

In the last days i was trying to figure out how footprints for KiCAD work.
With help from people of this forum, i have achieved in completed all the footprints except one.

I have a pushbutton for an arduino shield.
This is the description of the button:
https://www.cableworks.gr/ilektronika/arduino-and-microcontrollers/components-and-ic/buttons/5pcs-momentary-tactile-push-button-switch-6x6x6mm-for-arduino/

As you can see there is no datasheet.

I have been trying to figure out how to find a footprint for many hours but i have not reached a conclusion yet.

KiCAD has "codes" to contain information in their footprint libraries, but i have not found documentation on what these codes are.

This is a Through Hole button, but i plan to use it as an SMD one.

I am looking at the Button_Switch_SMD library.

There are hundreds of footprints in there.

The dimensions of the button are 6mm X 6mm.

The distance between the two pins on each side is around 4mm.

I am sorry to ask what some people may consider basic, but i am very frustated and i am one step from designing the board and sending to the board house. Google didn't prove much useful in this case, just KiCAD forum links, 3 years ago, with different libraries.

Comment: What I usually do is buy the parts first, bend legs or whatnot, then measure the part with a micrometer. *Then* pick a KiCAD package which will work (and double-check the footprint dimensions.)  If none fit perfectly, then design a custom footprint.  Check all dimensions again to ensure it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those switches are fairly standard.  I'm not sure if you're planning on bending the leads out or in, but the SW_Push_1P1T_NO_CK_KSC6xxJ footprint looks like it should work.

Comment: I am planning on bending the leads outward, so i convert them to SMD buttons.

Comment: In that case, I suggest using the SW_SPST_PTS645 since that gives you a bit of a wider footprint.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a little tedious to make one from scratch, but almost all the time spent is for the artwork. Making the pads is really easy in Kicad, and the mask layers generally come out automatically. Like everything else, the first one takes 5x as long. Google "kicad footprint tutorial" or similar. It'll be worth your time, since this is an unavoidable part of the process.